# Controls Added dynamically not showing up in User control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to repeat some set of fields(textboxes) web form UI when user clicks on `Add` button on page.  Initially, they see one control with few fields, when they click Add another set of the same fields will be added to the Page.
So I made a user control of the repeating UI and when the user clicks on Add button on Page, I am trying to generate the textboxes dynamically and add it to the Page. 
But for some reason, my dynamically generated UI is not visible. I believe this could be a view state issue. but not sure how to solve it.

Here's the code that I am trying to add to Usercontrol's update panel on button click method of user control.

```
protected void AddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel panel = AddPanel(this.NumberOfDynamicControls);
        AddVRMOrSink(panel, this.NumberofTextBoxes, this.NumberOfDynamicControls);

        this.NumberOfDynamicControls++; // update number of controls   
    }

private void AddVRMOrSink(Panel panel, int textboxCounter, int i)
    {
        string[] labels = this.DisplayNames.Split('_');

        TableRow tRow1 = new TableRow();
        TableRow tRow2 = new TableRow();
        TableRow tRow3 = new TableRow();
        TableRow tRow4 = new TableRow();
        tRow1.Width = new Unit(350, UnitType.Pixel);
        tRow2.Width = new Unit(350, UnitType.Pixel);
        tRow3.Width = new Unit(350, UnitType.Pixel);
        tRow4.Width = new Unit(350, UnitType.Pixel);

        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell21 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell22 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell31 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell32 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell41 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell42 = new TableCell();

        tRow1.Cells.Add(cell1);
        tRow1.Cells.Add(cell2);

        tRow2.Cells.Add(cell21);
        tRow2.Cells.Add(cell22);

        tRow3.Cells.Add(cell31);
        tRow3.Cells.Add(cell32);

        tRow4.Cells.Add(cell41);
        tRow4.Cells.Add(cell42);

        TextBox txt_1 = AddTextBox(textboxCounter++, true);
        TextBox txt_2 = AddTextBox(textboxCounter++);
        TextBox txt_3 = AddTextBox(textboxCounter++);
        TextBox txt_4 = AddTextBox(textboxCounter++);
        TextBox txt_5 = AddTextBox(textboxCounter++);

        Label lbl_1 = AddLabel(labels[0]);
        Label lbl_2 = AddLabel(labels[1]);
        Label lbl_3 = AddLabel(labels[2]);
        Label lbl_4 = AddLabel(labels[3]);
        Label lbl_5 = AddLabel(labels[4]);


        Button deleteButton = AddDeleteButton(i + 1);

        cell1.Controls.Add(lbl_1);
        cell1.Controls.Add(txt_1);

        cell2.Controls.Add(lbl_2);
        cell2.Controls.Add(txt_2);

        cell22.Controls.Add(lbl_3);
        cell22.Controls.Add(txt_3);

        cell32.Controls.Add(lbl_4);
        cell32.Controls.Add(txt_4);

        cell42.Controls.Add(lbl_5);
        cell42.Controls.Add(txt_5);

        panel.Controls.Add(tRow1);
        panel.Controls.Add(tRow2);
        panel.Controls.Add(tRow3);
        panel.Controls.Add(tRow4);

        panel.Controls.Add(deleteButton);

        this.ControlsTable.Rows.Add(tRow1);
        this.ControlsTable.Rows.Add(tRow2);
        this.ControlsTable.Rows.Add(tRow3);
        this.ControlsTable.Rows.Add(tRow4);

        if (!isVRM)
        {
            Label lbl_6 = AddLabel(labels[5]);
            TextBox txt_6 = AddTextBox(textboxCounter++);
            TableRow tRow5 = new TableRow();
            tRow5.Width = new Unit(350, UnitType.Pixel);
            TableCell cell51 = new TableCell();
            TableCell cell52 = new TableCell();
            TableCell cell53 = new TableCell();

            cell52.Controls.Add(lbl_6);
            cell52.Controls.Add(txt_6);
            cell53.Controls.Add(deleteButton);

            tRow5.Cells.Add(cell51);
            tRow5.Cells.Add(cell52);
            tRow5.Cells.Add(cell53);

            panel.Controls.Add(tRow5);
            this.ControlsTable.Rows.Add(tRow5);
        }
        else
        {
            TableCell cell43 = new TableCell();
            cell43.Controls.Add(deleteButton);
            tRow4.Cells.Add(cell43);
        }
        UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(panel);
        DynamicControlPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(panel);
    }
```

The usercontrol.ascx is

```html
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GenericVRMSINKControl.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="ABC.UI.UserControls.RequestControls.GenericVRMSINKControl" %>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:HiddenField ID="numberOfControls" Value="1" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" />
      <asp:PlaceHolder ID="DynamicControlPlaceHolder" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="staticControlsPanel" runat="server">
          <asp:Table Width="100%" runat="server" ID="ControlsTable">
            <asp:TableRow Style="width: 350px">
              <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" ID="PinNos" EnableTheming="false" Width="110pt">
                </asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_PinNos" runat="server" Width="140pt" TextMode="MultiLine">
                </asp:TextBox>
              </asp:TableCell>
              <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" ID="FieldNameLabel1" EnableTheming="false" Width="110pt">
                </asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="FieldValueTextBox1" runat="server" Width="140pt">
                </asp:TextBox>
              </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow Style="width: 350px">
              <asp:TableCell>
              </asp:TableCell>
              <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" ID="FieldNameLabel2" EnableTheming="false" Width="110pt">
                </asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="FieldvalueTextBox2" runat="server" Width="140pt">
                </asp:TextBox>
              </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow Style="width: 350px">
              <asp:TableCell>
              </asp:TableCell>
              <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" ID="FieldNameLabel3" EnableTheming="false" Width="110pt">
                </asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="FieldvalueTextBox3" runat="server" Width="140pt">
                </asp:TextBox>
              </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow Style="width: 350px">
              <asp:TableCell>
              </asp:TableCell>
              <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" ID="FieldNameLabel4" EnableTheming="false" Width="110pt">
                </asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="FieldvalueTextBox4" runat="server" Width="140pt">
                </asp:TextBox>
              </asp:TableCell>
              <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Button ID="addBtn" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="AddBtn_Click" Text="Add" Width="66px" Height="26px" Visible="true" />
              </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
          </asp:Table>
        </asp:Panel>
      </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Any idea on what am I missing here?

Comment: you able to see first time?

Comment: Yes, but not on subsequent clicks to Add button..Not sure why...:(

Comment: dynamic control doesnot maintain their state , you you need to prepopulate them in pre-int stage ..

Comment: So..can u give me more details...or an example or w link for me to go through and understand

Comment: But why the first click to add was successful and the rest were not?

Comment: you can google it , you will find a numerous articles about it, on your first click at that time only first initializzed control will be available , i.e the state between your dynamic control creation ----> first click in between these there is no postback so that is the reason you can able to achieve it , once you click it ... there it goes..

Comment: I googled it..but couldn't find much help..hence posted here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143458/discussion-between-webruster-and-programmerzzz).